# Separate Integer From Arabic String PHP

Tags: php

how i separate a integer number from a given string with comma separate values. I have tried but not succeeded.

```
$Q22V=نعم1,لا2,نعم3,لا4,نعم5,لا6,نعم7,لا8,نعم9,لا10,نعم11,لا12

list($num,$letter) = preg_split('/(?<=\d)(?=[a-z]+)/i',$Q22v);
echo "- ".$letter."<span style=float:right>$ ".$num ."</span> <br>";
```

I want to display result like this

```
نعم 1

2 لا

3 لا
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$Q22V = "نعم1,لا2,نعم3,لا4,نعم5,لا6,نعم7,لا8,نعم9,لا10,نعم11,لا12";

$items = explode(',', $Q22V);

foreach($items as $item){
   preg_match('/([^0-9]*)([0-9]+)/', $item, $matches);
   $letter = $matches[1];
   $num = $matches[2];
   echo $num . ' ' . $letter . '<br/>';
}
```

Explode the string on `,` to separate the string on commas.
Then use a regular expression to separate the numbers from the non-numbers.
`$num` will contain the number while `$letter` will contain the Arabic characters.
Output should be similar to your example output.

Comment: It is returning this as string Ù†Ø¹Ù…??

Comment: For my output I get:

1 نعم

2 لا

3 نعم

4 لا

5 نعم

6 لا

7 نعم

8 لا

9 نعم

10 لا

11 نعم

12 لا

Comment: That's my entire script. I'm thinking I'm not seeing the characters the same way as you.